# How to get static ip/domain of facebook webhook request

Tags: api, facebook, graph, webhooks

I have a query regarding facebook webhook IP/Domain whitelisting.

we are deploying an application in Enterprise Organization where organization wants us to let them know a domain/ip from which the request should be served only.

the thing is is there any domain, endpoint or ip address which can be whitelisted so webhook can work.

currently every webhook request is giving different remote address.

Regards

Comment: Not sure if anything like that is documented anywhere. You _could_ try and see if the use the same IP ranges/servers to make webhook requests, as their crawler does - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler But even if that was the case right now, there is probably no guarantee that without official mention, it would always stay this way.

Comment: Pretty sure the crawler page list all Facebook IP addresses. So it should cover the ones that does webhook requests. But if you use that list make sure you keep it updated because it changes all the time. But I would really recommend not using a whitelist. It will just cause problems.

Comment: And it is impossible to give you a domain. Domains are not doing requests. Domains are just a way to find an IP address to do a request to.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.